# Is the double dollar sign ($$) quotation method in SQL standard?

Tags: postgresql, sql-standard

In PostgreSQL, strings can be quoted very flexibly using a pair of dollar signs (`$`) with a tag in between. For example,

```
SELECT $f$ Hi $f$;
```

*Is this quoting mechanism a part of any SQL standard, or is it postgres specific?*

Answer (score 1):

NO, its postgresql specific. Many programing languages offer a way to write text that avoids having to be escaped.

consider

```
Select $$";"'\e\r\n$$
```

vs

```
select '\";\"\'\\e\\r\\n'
```

Also keep in mind that since version 9.1 Postgtesql, by default, will no longer allow passing strings with escape literals(\) in a query. In order to do this, it has to have a leading E

```
select E'\r\n'
```

to be escaped now
[see standard conforming string](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/runtime-config-compatible.html)

Comment: consider vetting & sharing your code samples and expected output. I can't figure out what you're meaning to do with the 2nd example. perhaps [start here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=87610b9c56b7434ab33dbd1804189b46) and [edit your answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/posts/255370/edit) with the updated link once it reflects the output you mean to show?

Comment: the 2nd example is example is C style escaped string    https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-STRINGS-ESCAPE  with standard_conforming_string off

Comment: I'm getting the same syntax error both locally and [on shareable code](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=a3c7317c48d9dcbfeb79e69b77dee811) with that set option. Might just be me borking it, but in general providing a rigorous [repro] will improve an answer

Comment: it should work  not sure why not  Because doing   select E'\' \r\n'  does work   of course doing the other method to escape ' works   yet it did not escape slashes correctly either  it returned double slashes.  wonder if this behavior changed at some point and i missed it